# Applying a condition for all similar values within a column in a Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataset in a pandas dataframe:

```
Patient_ID       Image_Type ...    

P001             Paired
P001             Paired
P001             Paired
P001             CBCT
P002             CBCT
P002             CBCT
P002             CBCT
P002             CBCT
P002             CBCT
P002             CBCT
P003             CBCT
...              ...
```

So what im trying to do is to find whether the number of datapoints for each patient (Patient_ID) is equal to the number CBCT images taken for that patient.

For example for Patient P002, the number CBCT images taken is equal to the number of datapoints. And for Patient P001, the number of CBCT images taken does not equal to the total number of datapoints for that partient. I would like to assign this condition to a new column; where value = 'Yes' if it is true and 'No' where it false.

Please let me know if you need clarificartions with my question. Thanks.

Comment: When you say you want to create a new column, is this on the original dataframe?

Comment: Yes, I would like to add a new column to the original dataframe.

Answer (score -1):

IIUC:

```
df[df["Image_Type"] == "CBCT"].groupby("Patient_ID").size() == df.groupby("Patient_ID").size()

#Patient_ID
#P001    False
#P002     True
#P003     True
#dtype: bool
```

I'm using `df` as

```
   Patient_ID Image_Type
0        P001     Paired
1        P001     Paired
2        P001     Paired
3        P001       CBCT
4        P002       CBCT
5        P002       CBCT
6        P002       CBCT
7        P002       CBCT
8        P002       CBCT
9        P002       CBCT
10       P003       CBCT
```

Comment: Yes that is what I'm trying to do, but when I try this in my own dataframe I get the following error: ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects.
​What does this mean?

Comment: @msekhon try this: `df[df["Image_Type"] == "CBCT"].groupby("Patient_ID")["Image_Type"].size() == df.groupby("Patient_ID")["Image_Type"].size()`

Comment: @msekhon also try updating your pandas version

Comment: I have tried your suggestions it still not working. I now know what the problem is. The length of `df[df["Image_Type"] == "CBCT"].groupby("Patient_ID")["Image_Type"].size()` is not the same as `df.groupby("Patient_ID")["Image_Type"].size()`. This is because some patients did not have a CBCT image taken and thus does not show on the following list `df[df["Image_Type"] == "CBCT"].groupby("Patient_ID")["Image_Type"].size()`. Any suggestions?